# Converting String to NSDate Giving Wrong Date

Tags: ios, swift, date, nsdate, uidatepicker

I have a String that I converted using `stringFromDate` and now I'm trying to convert it back, however when the UIPicker starts, it's giving me the wrong day

```
 let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
 dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MMM YYYY"

 print(birthday) // logs 15 Jan 1992

 let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(birthday)
 self.datePicker.setDate(date!, animated: true)
```

I tried hardcoding `"15 Feb 1992"` but still the same result. The date on UIDatePicker shows 22 Dec 1991 on Start.

If I use hardcore `10 Jan 1980`, it starts from 23 December 1979.

(I don't know if that's the case but I have `MMM dd YYYY` in UIPickerView whereas it's `dd MMM YYYY` for the strings.. I don't think though because while saving, it saves the right value)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong format. You need `dd MMM yyyy`.

Comment: Should I use this while saving too? Because I was using `dd MMM YYYY` and it's working on saving.. Just for learning..

Comment: Always use `yyyy` for the year unless you have a specific and understood reason why you need to use `YYYY`. They are not the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

To use correct format string is most important..

YYYY is week-based calendar year. (used in ISO week-year calendar)

yyyy is ordinary calendar year.

so, You should use 'yyyy' instead of 'YYYY'.

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MMM yyyy"

print(birthday)  

let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(birthday)
self.datePicker.setDate(date!, animated: true)
```

For more string format for Date: refer this link

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thank you, I kept getting some weird date. Ie. I had 10062017 and I got 24-12-2016 all because I had YYYY instead of yyyy.